# db interface problems c#

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I am using a listview to print all my tables in a database with the number of values each one is containing. My problem is that when i first started the project the values were correct and now some of them are +1. No line of code is affecting this, I've started another project and the problem persists.

This is the button function:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Clear();
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Tabel");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Numar campuri");
        List<string> tables = GetTables(conString);
        List<string> numbers = GetNum(conString);
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.Count(); i++)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(tables[i]).SubItems.Add(numbers[i].ToString());
        }
        listView1.Columns[0].Width = -1;
        listView1.Columns[1].Width = -2;
        listView1.Columns[1].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    }
```

GetTables(name of table) and GetNum(number of data):

```
   public static List<string> GetTables(string connectionString)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
            List<string> TableNames = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
            {
                TableNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
            }
            return TableNames;
        }
    }
    public static List<string> GetNum(string connectionString)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
            List<string> TableNum = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
            {
                TableNum.Add(row[7].ToString());
            }
            return TableNum;
        }
    }
```

I've printed the datatable from GetNum and found out that row[7] is printing the number of values from the specific table.

The db is local - xampp

What is the issue ?

Comment: Why don't you have one method that gets the table name and count together instead of running the same query to the DB twice? You can use a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` or in C# 7 or later `List<(string, string)>`

Comment: Haven't though about that, thanks!
Still the problem persists :)

Comment: A guess: this is not always the exact number of rows, but rather an approximate number used by a query optimizer. It is only updated "occasionally" for performance reasons

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a dynamically formed query to get your row count and return a dictionary (if table names are unique), otherwise use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, int> GetTables(string connectionString)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable schema = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
            Dictionary<string, int> TableNames = new Dictionary<string, int> ();
            foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
            {
                string tableName = row[2].ToString();
                int countOfRows = GetNum(connectionString, tableName);
                TableNames.Add(tableName , countOfRows);
            }
            return TableNames;
        }
    }
    public static int GetNum(string connectionString, string tableName)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            //do query here 
            string query = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}", tableName);
            //result = connection -> get results from query
            //return result;
        }
    }
```